# Custom container.html.twig

Tags: views, theming, 8

I need to delete a div made by the container.html.twig. How can I rename this template to this specific region?

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'container' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/newbikes/templates/system/container.html.twig' -->
<div class="form-group">
```

thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220237/override-a-template-for-only-one-route

Answer (score 1):

Copy core template to your theme template folder (yourtheme/templates) core/themes/stable/templates/form/container.html.twig and clear caches.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer. I assume that they're asking how to specifically remove the container in that one instance, not sitewide. It only suggests a global template rather than ones that are more specific. The answer would probably really be to use a preprocess.