# Override a template for only one route

Tags: theming, 8

I want override the region default template. I did that with a hook theme from my module. 
I want override the region custom template but only for the front page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x)() in your theme.
For *siderbar_first* region it would look like follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_region_alter(&$suggestions, $vars) {
  if ($vars['elements']['#region'] == 'sidebar_first' && Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $suggestions[] = 'region__sidebar_first__front';
  }
}
```

Now *region--sidebar-first--front.html.twig* can be used for theming sidebar on the front page.